# Friendly URL may contain or not parameter

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I have a frindly(not so much but fits me well) URL expression on my HTACCESS.
The page treats accordly with "mode" and ids

For editing a category:

```
#URL
    edit.php?mode=cat&cat=1
#The expression
    RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /edit.php?mode=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]
#Output
    /editar/cat/1
```

Editing subcategory:

```
#URL
    edit.php?mode=subcat&cat=1&subcat=1
#The expression
    RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /edit.php?mode=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3 [NC,L]
#Output
    /editar/subcat/1/1
```

Editing product:

```
#URL
    edit.php?mode=prod&cat=1&subcat=1&prod=1
#The expression
    RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /edit.php?mode=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3&prod=$4 [NC,L]
#Output
    /editar/prod/1/1/1
```

So far, so good!

But I have three expressions for the same page.

```
RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /edit.php?mode=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /edit.php?mode=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /edit.php?mode=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3&prod=$4 [NC,L]
```

Is there any way to reduce that to just ONE expression, where some varible might be or might no be present on the string?

Like: edit.php?mode=prod&cat=1   THIS -> &subcat=1 AND THIS -> &prod=1 being optional?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$  - [E=PASS:mode=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3&prod=$4]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PASS} ^((mode=(.*))&subcat=&prod=|(mode=(.*)&subcat=(.+))&prod=|(mode=(.*)&subcat=(.+)&prod=(.+)))$
RewriteRule ^    /edit.php?%2%4%7 [L,NE]
```

So , with the code above you will be able to handle requests like the following :

```
/editar/1 or editar/1/     = not match
/editar/1/2 or editar/1/2/   = match and redirect to /edit.php?mode=1&cat=2
/editar/1/2/3 or editar/1/2/3/   = match and redirect to /edit.php?mode=1&cat=2&subcat=3
/editar/1/2/3/4  = match and redirect to /edit.php?mode=1&cat=2&subcat=3&prod=4
/editar/1/2/3/4/    = not match
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

Comment: Worked very well, Mohammed. Thank you very much! Can you suggest some read about these regex or could give me a brief explain about it?(the regex you did)

Comment: @KauêPorte glad to help , read first this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html then this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/modse_tenvif.html so , i used mod_setenvif  against URI  then utilize from that by adding fixed parameters , your  given parameters, then match against them in condition ,RewriteCond, according to their content and finally do the last rule according to previous condition

Answer (score 0):

You can make the 3rd and 4th capture-groups optional in your pattern.

```
RewriteRule ^editar/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /edit.php?mode=$1&cat=$2subcat=$3&prod=$4 [NC,L]
```

But doing this, you will get empty `subcat` and `product` value if the uri is `/editar/foo/bar` .

Comment: That would be no problem. If the mode is CAT, only the first ID is necessary. The others won't be used. The thing is, in you code, only the editar/cat/1 works... editar/subcat/1/1 and editar/prod/1/1/1 are both not working.